# how can i get the CheckOut date alwayse greater & maximal then the Checkin date in php

Tags: php, date, input

am trying to get a reservation form for my project so i code this :

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">                           
                        <label for="In"><i class="far fa-calendar-plus"></i> CheckIn</label>
                        <input type="date"  class="form-control" id="In" name="checkIn">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="Out"><i class="far fa-calendar-plus"></i> Depart</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" min="<?php minDate() ; ?>" id="Out" name="checkOut">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </form>
```

then i call the function `minDate()`  in the CheckOut input `min="<?php minDate() ; ?>"` attribute in order to hide the dates less then the CheckIn date

this is the function :

```
 function minDate(){

    if(isset($_POST['checkIn'])){

        $date = $_POST['checkIn'];  

    }

    echo $date;
}
```

but this is not working , the dates less then the check in date didn't hide

can i get some help !_!

Comment: `$_POST['checkIn']` isn't defined inside the function.

Comment: i use that in many functions and it's worked ... you don't need to define it ..because when you call the function the ` $_POST['checkIn']` is gonna be a global variable

Comment: Funk Forty Niner at least give me a solution or link to previous question that i duplicate it  !